# Batch convert 4 PDF pages to one PDF page

Tags: pdf, imagemagick

I have a PDF with 100 pages. How can I make a new PDF that displays 4 pages on one?

I know that I can do it with Chrome by printing the PDF to new PDF and change this in the options. But I want to make it for a lot of files and put it as a script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most simple solution I recall to memory is to use `pdfnup`

> *`pdfnup` is written and maintained by David Firth as part of the PDFjam package*

**Use**
If the original name for the file is `MyFile.pdf` the syntax can be something similar to

```
pdfnup MyFile.pdf --no-landscape --nup 2x2 --column true
```

and it will create a file named `MyFile-nup.pdf`.
After you checked and chose the right options from the *commandline* you can include it as command in your script.

This runs on Unix-like OSes (or Windows with Cygwin and the tetex-extras package installed).  It requires that [pdfpages](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages) and [pdfTeX](http://www.tug.org/applications/pdftex/) also be installed (and other packages for specific cases).  See details in the pdfjam link under References, below.

**Note**
The use of `imagemagick` should present problems related with the internal conversion in images in the process `pdf---> images --->pdf`. TO have an idea see [*"Convert PDF to image with high resolution"*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6605006/3569208).

**References**

- [You can read more about `pdfjam` here.](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic-research/firth/software/pdfjam/)
- Quick references with `pdfnup --help`.